# Regular expression that allows letters (like "ñ") from any language

Tags: php, regex, unicode, internationalization

trying to let users use special characters in other languages such as Spanish or French. I originally had this:

```
 "/[^A-Za-z0-9\.\_\- ]/i"
```

and then changed it to

```
 "/[^\p{L}\p{N}\.\_\-\(\) ]/i"
```

but still doesn't work. letters such as "ñ" should be allowed. Thanks.

Revision:
I found that adding a (*UTF8) at the beginning helps solve the problem. So I'm using the following code:"/(*UTF8)[^\p{L}A-Za-z0-9._- ]/i"

Revision:
After looking at the answers I decided to use: "/[^\p{Xwd}. -]/u". Thanks(It works even with the Chinese alphabet.

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) is always useful.

Comment: allow everything, then nothing you need to do

Comment: @Dagon The intent appears to be to allow *letters* (and numbers and a few specials characters), not *everything* :)

Comment: but why not everyting ?

Comment: Your regex is correct; the problem lies with how you're using it. Can you post some of the PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for latin languages you can use the `\p{Latin}` character class:

```
/[^\p{Latin}0-9._ -]/u
```

But if you want all other letters and digits:

```
/[^\p{Xwd}. -]/u
```

The "u" modifier indicates that the string must be read as an unicode string.

Comment: How to do "all other letters" rather than "all other letters and digits"? Removing the d after Xw causes it to match nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into specifying a [unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en) range, ie. `[\w\u00C0-\u024F.-]+` to include Latin extended letters. But it's hard to try and restrict characters to such a broad subset; what about Chinese, Vietnamese, etc.? I'm with Dagon on this one – best to allow anything.