# how to allow letters and enye only

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Where do I put the enye in my regex validation? Do i just put it beside regex for letters?
I want to accept enyes in fname,lname, and mname.

```
return [
                    'fname' => 'required|max:255|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',
                    'lname' => 'required|max:255|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',
                    'mname' => 'max:255|alpha',
                     'file' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
               'contact_no' => 'regex:/^[-0-9\+]+$/',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
                'school_id' => 'required|exists:schools,id',
                'degree_id' => 'required|exists:degrees,id',
        ];
```

Comment: enye? as in `&ntilde;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression that allows letters (like "ñ") from any language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052517/regular-expression-that-allows-letters-like-%c3%b1-from-any-language)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer guys but I got it working. I just used

```
return [
                    'fname' => 'required|max:255|regex:/^[a-zA-ZÑñ\s]+$/',
                    'lname' => 'required|max:255|regex:/^[a-zA-ZÑñ\s]+$/',
                    'mname' => 'max:255|alpha',
                     'file' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
               'contact_no' => 'regex:/^[-0-9\+]+$/',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
                'school_id' => 'required|exists:schools,id',
                'degree_id' => 'required|exists:degrees,id',
        ];
```

Comment: I suggest you to read about [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and perform your task by using the right Laravel way - http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: @limonte uhm I just followed how Laravel uses Form Request for validations. Do you really need to downvote it?

Comment: What you've done works if the character encoding of your editor happens to match the character encoding of wherever your test strings are coming from (database, http request, ...) AND that encoding is a single-byte extended-ASCII encoding.  It will fail, or accept unexpected characters, if you editor encodes enye's in 2+ bytes.  Lower case enye in utf8 is two bytes: xC3B1.  Your pattern in your code will accept any bytes c3 or b1 even if they are not beside each other.  Use mb-aware functions like the other answer.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder The Laravel [validateRegex](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L1364) method that is called in this case uses `preg_match`, but adding the `u` (PCRE_UTF8) to the expression should avoid the issues you've highlighted, without the need to use `mb_regex_encoding` and `mb_ereg`.

Answer (score 0):

The bytes it needs to match for enye depends on the character encoding of your string (hopefully it is utf8).  So you'll need a multibyte encoding-aware regex function.  Fortunately, PHP has 'em ...

```
$pattern = '/^[ñÑa-zA-Z\s]+$/';
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_ereg($pattern, $testString, $matches);
```

where `$pattern` has your regex with enye's typed in with UTF8 encoding.